# Problem with accessing a website hosted on a local device connected to the local wireless network

Tags: web-server, hostname, dhcp-server, dns-server

I am running `Lighttpd 1.4.28` on an embedded device. Apart from the webserver, I run `udhcpd` and `dnsmasq` to allow other devices to connect to my embedded device to access the website.

My device has the capability to join other networks. So when I make my embedded device join my local home wireless network, I am able to access the website with the IP obtained by this device after joining the local home network, but not by the hostname.

When I join the local home network, I kill the `udhcpd` server as my local home network has a DHCP Server and DNS Server running which automatically assigns the IP.

I pass the hostname of my device when requesting IP through `udhcpc` as:

`udhcpc -h "www.mydevice.com"`

My problem is I am only able to access the website running on the device as :

`http://192.168.100.101/index.html`

and not as:

`http://www.mydevice.com/index.html`

Can anybody tell me where am I going wrong? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hostname shouldn't be `www.mydevice.com`, but it should be `www` in this case. `mydevice.com` is your domain and should be the domain name of your home network.

Both `udhcpd` and `dnsmasq` should be configured to this domain. Even your PCs should have been configured to this DNS domain name.

Also make sure, that mydevice.com is not a real domain that has an own DNS server in the Internet. In this case you should either name it to something unreal like `mydevice.invalid` or create a subdomain for that purpose like `local.mydevice.com`. Otherwise you get in trouble with conflicting public and private DNS entries.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer... You seem to be pointing me on the right track... when my hostname is set as `www.mydevice.com` it shows the terminal prompt as `root@www.com`... which means my hostname is taken as `www` as you are saying..

Comment: Can you suggest me what settings / configurations should I do to access the website running on my embedded device after it gets connected to the local wireless network...?

Comment: Why should that be different? Configure your DHCP server to give out an IP for that hostname and then access it via the hostname. Nothing special.

Comment: +1 for that comment... I understand this, but can be kind enough to suggest me as to how can I configure my DHCP server to give out an IP for that hostname?

Comment: This is already answered here http://serverfault.com/questions/136332/setting-up-dnsmasq-for-a-local-network with also a reference to the documentation. Asking how to do this, is a new question you should create.