# Does dnsmasq require www?

Tags: dnsmasq, firefox

I have 2 Linux servers on my local network:

1. An Nginx server, running a static website
2. A newly installed dnsmasq server

The Nginx web server has a static IP and I added it to the /etc/hosts file in the dnsmasq server. nslookup works fine and sees the correct IP address for the web server.
When I try to access the web server using its name, it works from chrome, chromium and MS Edge. It also works from Firefox on Windows. But it fails on Firefox on Linux. I added another row in the hosts file, which is the same name but with www and it seems to help the Firefox on Linux. How come Chromium opens the website without the www but Firefox does not?

Comment: What other testing did you do? Did you run nslookup (or dig) queries from each of the client machines? Have you ensured that the dnsmasq machine is the only dns server you clients are querying? The fact that it doesn't work in FF is interesting, but provides little data.
Consider the answer from this detailed DNSmasq question: https://serverfault.com/questions/136332/setting-up-dnsmasq-for-a-local-network?rq=1
I suspect you will find useful guidance in getting set up.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is a firefox configuration issue.

On your linux machine type in the firefox address bar `about:config` (press  Enter)

Promise to be careful, when asked.

Type in the search bar and look for the preference :
`browser.fixup.alternate.prefix`
and set its value to `false`.
Then close and restart  Firefox.